Should I use SameSite:None cookies on an API which authenticates users on other domains?
I have a frontend, an API, and a gateway to this API.
An user in frontend makes a login request to this gateway (https) which redirects this request to an API running on localhost (http) linux, if username and pass match so the API sets a jwt token on a cookie in order to user gets authenticated on others API routes, but since I have a gateway in the middle of it I needed to set SameSite:None on the cookie containing jwt if I wouldn't do that the cookie would reach the gateway with null value so on posterior requests it wouldn't pass cookie further to the authenticated routes in the API. The problem is I realized this method is vulnerable to CSRF attacks, the question is am I right setting SameSite:None cookie and I just need use CSRF token or am I wrong using this kind of cookie for that situation?

Additionaly, is it a problem the api is running on http for attackers can't access directly localhost?
